# chrome headless print-to-pdf has poor quality

Tags: google-chrome

Use this command to convert html to pdf:

```
google-chrome-stable --headless --print-to-pdf-no-header --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw https://image.taidii.cn/upload/portfoliov6/2020_09_22_15_11_38_56026bdb-d914-4673-86c1-0dc27ffcfad3.html?is_hd=1
```

[image: use headless print-to-pdf]

use print and you can see this one is much better.
So do i miss any headless options, can anyone tell me? Thanks!!!
[image: use print]